# My javascript output does not match the expected output. I don't know where I went wrong

Tags: javascript, function, range

> Write a program that predicts the approximate size of a population of
>   organisms. Use the following data:
>
> - Starting number of organisms: 2
> - Average daily increase: 30%
> - Number of days to multiply: 10
>
> The program should display the following table of data:

```
Day              Approiximate Population
1                                   2

2                                   2.6

3                                   3.38

4                                   4.39

5                                   5.71

6                                   7.42

7                                   9.65

8                                   12.54

9                                   16.31

10                                 21.20
```

My code is not outputting the same Approximate Population. Where did I go wrong?
Here is my code:

```
    var NumOfOrganisms = 2;
    var DailyIncrease = .30; 
    var NumOfDays;

    for(NumOfDays = 1; NumOfDays <= 10; NumOfDays++){
        calculation(NumOfOrganisms, DailyIncrease, NumOfDays);
    }

    function calculation(organisms, increase, days){
        var calculation = (organisms * increase) + days;
        console.log("increase is " + calculation);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not take in consideration the evolving population.

```
var NumOfOrganisms = 2;
var DailyIncrease = .30;
var NumOfDays;

console.log('initial population', NumOfOrganisms);

for(NumOfDays = 2; NumOfDays <= 10; NumOfDays++) {
  NumOfOrganisms = (NumOfOrganisms * DailyIncrease) + NumOfOrganisms;
  console.log('increase is', NumOfOrganisms);
}
```

Comment: wow, I see my errors now. Thank you very very much for helping!

Comment: @agentmg123 I'm glad I could help. Don't forget to accept the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

shouldn't calculation equal something more like organisms+(organisms*increase)?  And then if you keep a running total, you don't need to feed your function the number of days